# javascript button actions are not responding

Tags: javascript, html, xcode

Today, I was creating a calculator, but when I click on the numbers nothing happenes.

- There are no messages in the console at all after the clicks

Code in GitHub: [https://github.com/GuillermoSalvador/A\](https://github.com/GuillermoSalvador/A%5C)

```js
const display = document.querySelector("#display");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("buttons");

buttons.forEach((item)=>{
    item.onclick=()=>{
        if(item.id=="clear"){
            display.innerText="";
        }else if(item.id=="backspace"){
            let string = display.innerText.toString();
            display.innerText=string.substr(0,string.length-1)
        } else if (display.innerText !=""&& item.id=="equal"){
            display.innerText = eval(display.innerText);
        } else if(display.innerText == "" && item.id=="equal"){
            display.innerText = "Null";
            setTimeout(()=>(display.innerText = ""), 2000);
        }else{
            display.innerText+=item.id;
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class ="container">
        <div class="calculator dark">
            <div class="theme-toggler">
                <i class="toggler-icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="display-screen">
                <div id="display"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="clear">C</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="/">/</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="*">*</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="backspace"> < </button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="7">7</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="8">8</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="9">9</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="-">-</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="4">4</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="5">5</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="6">6</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="+">+</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="1">1</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="2">2</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="3">3</button></td>
                        <td rowspan="2"><button class="btn-equal" id="equal">=</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id=".">.</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="0">0</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="00">00</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "why is your title in quotes"? Please include the code you are having an issue with in the question. A link to a github page is pointless since the code will change rendering this question useless for future readers - and 57 lines of HTML + 20 lines of javascript isn't a lot of code to post in a question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a moment to read [ask] and make sure to include a [mre] (don't post a link; post a relevant code snipped) as well as what exactly you're trying to do, what you've tried so far, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: hint: `document.querySelectorAll("buttons");` selects any elements named `<buttons>` - of which there are exactly zero - also, get used to using HTML entities such as `&lt;` instead of `<` in HTML - not your issue, but better to learn good habits early rather than late

Comment: @JaromandaX the quotes was a sneaky way to get around the SO prompt telling the user that the title was not a valid title and that the question was going to be off topic. Well done SO for that, and very sneaky of OP to get around the validation check

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at by @jaromanda-x in the comments, your selector for the buttons was wrong, the elements that you want to select are `button` so make sure you use that in the query:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
```

There are no errors or messages related to this in the console or the output because there are no runtime issues with the code.

Your current query: `document.querySelectorAll("button")` returns an empty array, because there are no `<buttons>` elements in the DOM. To debug click events in the future, put a console message in the handler, that way you know that the handler has been executed at all:

```
buttons.forEach((item)=>{
    item.onclick=()=>{
        console.log('button click: ' + item.id);
...
```

*Don't forget to remove of comment out these types of logs later, they are for simple diagnostics*

If there is no message in the console, then look into your code that registers the event, sometimes you might be using inline registration from the html or dynamic logic like your current example.

In the current code you could log out the number of buttons for instance:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
console.log(`buttons found: ${buttons}:${buttons. Length}`);
```

You can also use the console in the browser tools to execute javascript against your active page, so you could execute the `querySelectAll` in a *live* sense:

[image: console executing command]

You should find this simple tool very helpful both for rapid development but also your learning.

---

In the future, please use code snippets or [Stack-Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/1690217) to display simple html/javascript issues rather than a link to an external site. Issues like this are immediately obvious if we can see the code, but we don't want to have to leave SO to do that... Developers like me are inherently lazy ;)

```js
const display = document.querySelector("#display");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

console.log(`buttons found: ${buttons}:${buttons. Length}`);
buttons.forEach((item)=>{
    item.onclick=()=>{
        console.log('button click: ' + item.id);
        if(item.id=="clear"){
            display.innerText="";
        }else if(item.id=="backspace"){
            let string = display.innerText.toString();
            display.innerText=string.substr(0,string.length-1)
        } else if (display.innerText !=""&& item.id=="equal"){
            display.innerText = eval(display.innerText);
        } else if(display.innerText == "" && item.id=="equal"){
            display.innerText = "Null";
            setTimeout(()=>(display.innerText = ""), 2000);
        }else{
            display.innerText+=item.id;
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class ="container">
        <div class="calculator dark">
            <div class="theme-toggler">
                <i class="toggler-icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="display-screen">
                <div id="display"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="clear">C</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="/">/</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="*">*</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="backspace"> < </button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="7">7</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="8">8</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="9">9</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="-">-</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="4">4</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="5">5</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="6">6</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="+">+</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="1">1</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="2">2</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="3">3</button></td>
                        <td rowspan="2"><button class="btn-equal" id="equal">=</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id=".">.</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="0">0</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="00">00</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

swap buttons with button like this

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");